# Is there a simple way to put a datagrid into a combobox?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Is there a simple example of how to have a combobox show a datagrid instead of a list? I been trying SO and google but kept getting results that show how to put a combobox in a datagrid.

Comment: are you talking about having a combobox show up as one of the fields in a datagrid..? if so this would be at the Template level..not sure if your question was a typo or not..

Comment: What are you looking to achieve by doing that?

Comment: Why do you want to have a data grid in a combobox? Because it sounds kinda weird.

Comment: So my basic achievement is to a have a combo box that has a list of options and the extra comlumn would be use to give info about that option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's for sure possible. That is a power of `WPF`.

[This](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/xaml/5af72df7-5b0b-4ac2-be96-e24127040bbf/wpf-datagrid-as-combobox-dropdown-part-2.aspx) link explains how to do it.

Comment: Please avoid linking off-site unless you provide a summary so that your answer can stand on its own or if it is to the official documentation of the given technology. Links die...

Answer (score 2):

To answer your first question, "Is there a simple example of how to have a combobox show a datagrid instead of a list?" very straight: - the answer is no.

That said, there are a couple of different ways to accomplish something that *looks like* a DataGrid (ie list with columns).

A very simple sample with faking something that could look like a datagrid could be altering the combobox's ItemTemplate

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cb" ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Age}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

You can also use [`SharedSizeGroup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.definitionbase.sharedsizegroup.aspx) (and [`Grid.IsSharedSizeScope`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.issharedsizescope.aspx)) to synchronize the column widths accross all items resulting in a dynamic and aligned layout.

Comment: A DataGrid would be overkill anyway as it is usually not just for displaying data but also editing and adding.

Comment: This works nicely but I was wondering if it is possible to have a line separate the two columns? Is there a way to give the columns a header? And if I were to choose a row can I only have the first column show up in the combobox when it is not active.

Answer (score 0):

As I said, it's weird to me to use a ComboBox for this. Maybe you can do it like this:

```
 <ToggleButton x:Name="Toggle" Width="200" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <Popup IsOpen="{Binding ElementName=Toggle, Path=IsChecked}" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=Toggle}" Placement="Bottom" Width="{Binding ElementName=Toggle, Path=Width}">
        <DataGrid>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Test1" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Test2" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Popup>
```

It's only a example of course, and it's missing a few features like automatic Popup hiding. But you get the point.

Comment: The big advantage of this is also the fact, that you're not going to use datagrid in a template - which will simplify the bindings a bit.